# Css flow element take remaining width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am desperately trying to resize a div to the remaining space of the site.

I have a HTML like this

```
<nav> nnn </nav>
<main> xxx </main>
<aside> aaa </aside>
```

On regular notebooks, I display them like three columns:

```
nnn   xxx   aaa
      xxx
```

But for phones, I display them in another order,
more like:

```
nnn   xxx
aaa   xxx
```

So what I do in my css is

```
nav {
    float: left
}
main {
    float: right
}
```

This works as long as I give fixed width for both, like 50% each.
But I want the `nav`/`aside` part to be 170px and the `main` to take the remaining space.

During research I found other answers that say I should remove the float attribute, but then I cannot make the aside part to appear below the nav and right to the main part.

I tried some different display styles, like display:table-cell (but there's nothing like rowspan for the `main`) or display:inline-block but I absolutely cannot make it work.

Hope someone has an idea how I could achieve this layout without touching the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three column layout for desktops can easily be achieved via display table/table cell. The mobile layout, which requires you to arrange the columns in flipped c shape can be achieved as follows:

- Place the three blocks inside a wrapper
- Push the wrapper towards right using margin
- Float the first and third blocks left, pull them outside the wrapper using negative margins
- Float the second column right and make it 100% wide
- Add a clearfix to the wrapper (but you cannot use overflow hidden)

```css
nav {
  background: #CCF;
}
main {
  background: #CCC;
}
aside {
  background: #CFC;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 963px) {
  #wrapper {
    margin-left: 170px;
  }
  #wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
  }
  nav, aside {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin-left: -170px;
    width: 170px;
  }
  main {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>nnn</nav>
  <main>xxx<br>xxx</main>
  <aside>aaa</aside>
</div>
```